# Issue with adding a image at the end of tabs

Tags: tabs

I am trying to add add a button called shopping cart to my Tabs script. The new button is controlled if a checkbox is clicked. (Show). Im confused why the image is not showing. Any answers would be helpful.

Thank you.
Copy code

```
$(function() {
   var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({cookie:{expires:1}});

   $(".ui-tabs-panel").each(function(i){
      var totalSize = $(".ui-tabs-panel").size() - 1;

      var prevImage = "custom/images/prev.png";
      var nextImage = "custom/images/next.png";
      var atcImage = "custom/images/cart.jpg";

      if (i != 0) {
         prev = i;
         $(this).append("<img href='#' class='prev-tab mover' rel='" + prev + "' src='" + prevImage + "'></img>");
      }
      if (i != totalSize) {
         next = i + 2;
         $(this).append("<img href='#' class='next-tab mover' rel='" + next + "' src='" + nextImage + "'></img>");
      }
  if (i > 1) {
         atc = i + 2;
         $(this).append("<img href='#' class='atc-tab mover' rel='" + next + "' src='" + atcImage + "'></img>");
      }
$('input[name=FIELD_469]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
    $("img[src*=cart]").show();
}
else {
    $("img[src*=cart]").hide();
       }
   });


   $('.next-tab, .prev-tab, .atc-tab').click(function() {
      $tabs.tabs('select', $(this).attr("rel"));
      return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can not ask for clarification because of low level of my rating, but there are several things that I have noticed and some recomendations.

1) Your selector should look like 'img[src~="cart"]'
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/

2) If you use class 'mover' only for that images, you can use '.mover' selector, otherwise just add new class name.

3) Test your JQuery objects with Google Chrome using console.log($("selector")) (Tools->Developer Tools->Console)

4) I think it should be not 'this' but $(this)

```
$('input[name=FIELD_469]').click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
    $("img[src*=cart]").show();
}
```

If recommendations don't help, please provide more info about your form preferrably with example to see. Thanks

Comment: Hey, the problem is this is on a site that is a ecommerce internal site, so I cant show it..

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you still have problem.